# Reading and writing raw object to disk (istream) across compilers

Tags: c++

I've been porting over some old legacy code. It is 15 years old and used to compile with some old Borland compiler. We are not able to compile the old code due to missing dependencies/compiler.

We have something like this:

```
class SegmentParameterDataRecord
{
private:
  int32_t parameterId;
  double value;

public:
  SegmentParameterDataRecord() : parameterId(0), value(0.0) {}
  int32_t & getParameterId() { return parameterId; }
  double & getValue() { return value; }

  void read(std::istream & in);
  void write(std::ostream & out);
};
```

Note the `read` and `write` methods. Here they are:

```
void SegmentParameterDataRecord::read(std::istream & in)
{
  in.read((char *) this, sizeof(*this));
}

void SegmentParameterDataRecord::write(std::ostream & out)
{
  out.write((char *) this, sizeof(*this));
}
```

This brought up some concerns to me. Note that the old code casts to a `char *` and processes the data as raw bytes of memory. I believe I am running into problems when I ported this code over to the latest MinGW.

1) Is it possible that the internal memory representation of `SegmentParameterDataRecord` is different across compilers, and thus it would be problematic to `write` the `SegmentParameterDataRecord` on one compiler (15-year old Borland) and then `read` it on another compiler (recent MinGW)?

2) Is it possible that `sizeof(SegmentParameterDataRecord)` could be different from a 15-year old Borland compiler to today's MinGW?

3) How likely is this possibility?

Comment: I'd speculate that this was a 16-bit compiler, given the large amount of unused space in the struct.  If accurate, you ought to be able to rescue it with __attribute__((packed)).  Double-check by comparing sizeof(SegmentParameterDataRecord) on the old and new compilers.  You need the same value to have a shot at rescuing the data.

Comment: @HansPassant What do you mean by unused space?

Comment: Also curious what Hans means by unused space. I can confirm, though, that the binary file appears (not certain) to take up much more space for the object than G++. This is a hunch based on analyzing the binary.

Comment: Do you have old data that needs reading back into the system? If not could you rewrite the function to use text format rather than binary?

Comment: Yes, I must be able to open these old files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that sizeof(SegmentParameterDataRecord) could be different from a 15-year old Borland compiler to today's MinGW?

This is definitely possible. In fact, `sizeof(int)` can be different across compilers and across machines. For example, on a 32-bit machine, `sizeof(int)` is often 4 bytes, but on a 64-bit machine, `sizeof(int)` can be 8 bytes.

Comment: We modeled the original C++ implementation by replacing `int` and `long` with `int32_t` and `unsigned int` and `unsigned long` with `uint32_t`. So from that perspective the new code should now have the same primitive sizes as was seen on the original implementation.

Comment: On Windows 64-bit, `sizeof(int)` is still 4.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Which is why I qualified with "can be".

Comment: @MiyazawaKenji How are `int32_t`, etc. defined? Are these custom typedefs? If so, then you can definitely replace them with typedefs that preserve the sizes the rest of your code expects.

Comment: These are defined in cstdint to be guaranteed 32 bits

Comment: @MiyazawaKenji Even better. I wasn't aware of these standard typedefs.

Comment: Yeah, they rock, we end up using them on every project